# Proper MYSQL syntax for timestamp comparison and distinct results with certain exclusions

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows, calculated-columns

Sorry for asking, but I've never had to do such a complex MYSQL query before and I don't actually know what to google search in order to get the answer.

I have a poorly crafted database with a table of appointments of pregnant women that includes the day they came and the number of weeks pregnant they were at that time. I'm trying to select each one that should be 30 weeks right now but that doesn't already have a separate entry after 25 weeks pregnancy. I use the phone number to uniquely identify each person.

Since I really don't know how to formulate this query, this is the best I've come up with.

```
SELECT * FROM patientlist WHERE 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) - `weekspreg`*604800) > 29*604800 

AND 

    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)- `weekspreg`*604800) <= 30*604800 

AND
 /* a subquery that keeps out results where the phone number would show up elsewhere in the table for a woman with more than 25 weeks of pregnancy. */
```

There has to be a better solution than separately querying each of the results from the date range by phone number to see if the weekspreg is more than 25.

Thank you in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.
Obviously, in this case, you would need to provide fake or otherwsie anonymised data.

Answer (score 3):

Your entire `WHERE` is incorrect. A query can only have **ONE** `where` clause. You join multiple conditions with `and` and `or`, not `and where`:

```
WHERE foo AND bar  // correct
WHERE foo AND WHERE bar // syntax error
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it. I don't use MYSQL much. Any idea on how to reduce the results to just those where the phone number is not used for an appointment where the weekspreg is more than 25?

Comment: `where phonenumber = ''` or `where phonenumber is null` would do the trick, depending on what you mean by "not used"

Comment: The phone number is used to uniquely identify a pregnant woman. The results need to only show women that should be 30 weeks now and that haven't already come some time after 25 weeks. Phone ='' means only women that have no phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MySQL [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). For example, I'm not entirely certain what that last WHERE clause is trying to do, but I believe the first portion could be rewritten as something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patientlist
WHERE `date` - interval `weekspreg` week
   between now() - interval 29 week 
   and now() - interval 30 week
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I understand that's the general rule, but in this case I feel the user needs to read the entire section of the mysql manual to figure out what they want, and it seems like a bad idea to try and reformat that entire page into an inline SO answer :)

Comment: The last where clause is the question. It's the part of the query I don't know how to write where I would like to exclude from the results any row that contains a phone number found in the table where the weeks was more than 25.

Comment: So does the table `patientlist` also store their last visit?

Comment: No. patientlist isn't a list of unique people. A single person with an id of 54324 might be the same as the entry at id  54212. The names aren't necessarily spelled right or a single woman might use different last names depending on her mood. Multiple people with the same name have come in before.

Comment: Is there a better way to craft the query that doesn't involve looping through each woman at 30 weeks to see if her phone number was used before?

Comment: What I was trying to get at with my earlier question is "Where would we find the information regarding a patient's last visit?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62362/discussion-between-tml-and-aunt-jamaima).